# Calling sql from R

Tags: sql, r, shiny

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                 Driver = "xxx", 
                 Server = "xxxx", 
                 Database = "xx", uid = "xxx", pwd = "xxx")
```

ABove is the function to call sql queries
 and below is the code to call the table in R

```
fac <- dbGetQuery(con, "(select * from table where Category = '",input$Cat,"')") ##input$Cat is called in UI.R
```

But the above statement is not getting executed. Am i calling `'",input$Cat,"'` wrongly ?

Comment: you need to add a `paste0` in front of your request-string!
`fac <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select * from table where Category = '",input$Cat,"')"))`

Comment: Means. Sorry didn’t get you

Comment: `dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select * from table where Category = '", input$Cat, "'"))`